# Unable to absorb partition into primary OS partition

Tags: linux-mint, partition, dual-boot

I created a dual boot awhile ago on a 1 Terabyte SSD for Linux and Windows. Thinking I'd only need 100 (and that it was excessive), I've been happy for awhile.

Unfortunately, as I've spent more and more time and been learning more about Linux I've discovered a need for more space. I wanted to move 100 Gigabytes from Windows' free space over to my primary Linux boot.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

It's only allowing me to let my windows partition regain the space. What do I do about this? I have Gparted on a DVD and had attempted to do this the way I'd first done when I'd installed the dual-boot and grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expand your Linux ext4 partition because the unallocated space is not adjacent to the Linux partition.

You have two choices here - (1) move the Windows 10 partition to after the unallocated space or (2) create a Linux partition using the unallocated space and mount it via a suitable mount point into your existing Linux root file system.